# Remove points that do not fall on a line

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of 2d coordinates that creates line that is close to straight (ignoring outliers) line that looks something like this:

`[[0, 0], [1, 2], [2, 4], [6, 6], [7, 8], [5, 10], [6, 12], [7, 14]...]`
(Note the outliers [6, 8] and [12, 10])

The list is different each time. The line may not be straight and may not have any outliers. The list is always in order of y-value, like in the example. I have tried to use the angles between the points, but I couldn't find a solution that worked.

What the best way to remove the outliers from this list?

Comment: How can you know if a set of coordinates is part of a line or an outlier?

Comment: Which position in the list  [6, 8] and [12, 10]? Any attempted solution?

Answer (score 0):

Are the values for the first coordinate always 0,1,2,3,...? or might they be non-equidistant?

In the general case, where the first coordinate might be arbitrary, you can follow these steps:

1. make a linear regression (e.g. using sklearn)
2. find a distance between each point and the line.
3. mark every point with distance greater than a certain threshold as an outlier
4. remove outliers from list

ad 3) There might be multiple approaches for setting a good threshold, such as absolute distance of point to line in comparison to the average distance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches to this. If your set of points is relatively limited I would:

1. compute all possible lines passing by 2 points in your set
2. for each line assess if each point is an outlier or not
3. choose the line with the lowest amount of outliers

Here is an example of code doing that:

```
from itertools import combinations

points = [[0, 0],[1, 2], [2, 4], [6, 6], [7, 8], [5, 10], [6, 12], [7, 14]]

def line_parameters(points):
    # returns parameters a,b,c, of line ax+by+c=0 passing via the points    
    # horizontal line ie y + c = 0
    if points[0][1] == points[1][1]:
        return (0,1,-points[0][1])
    # vertical line ie x + c = 0
    elif points[0][0] == points[1][0]:
        return (1,0,-points[0][0])
    # with two points ax + by +c =0 can be simplified to x + by + c = 0
    else:
        b = -(points[0][0] - points[1][0]) / (points[0][1] - points[1][1])
        c = -(points[0][0] + b * points[0][1])
        return (1, b, c )

set_lines = set()
for c in combinations(points,2):
    set_lines.add(line_parameters(c))
set_lines = list(set_lines)

outliers_per_line = [[True for p in points] for line in set_lines]
for i,line in enumerate(set_lines):
    for j, point in enumerate(points):
        if point[0]*line[0]+point[1]*line[1]+line[2] ==0:
            outliers_per_line[i][j]=False

scores_per_line = [sum(line) for line in outliers_per_line]
best_score = min(scores_per_line)

for i in range(len(scores_per_line)):
    if scores_per_line[i] == best_score:
        print("Parameters of line ax+by+c=0:",set_lines[i])
        print(best_score,"outliers:",[points[j] for j in range(len(points)) if outliers_per_line[i][j]])
```

I can break down the steps if useful